# Which is the central atom in Lewis Dot Structures?

Tags: lewis-structure

What is the correct Lewis structure for hypochlorous acid, a compound containing chlorine, hydrogen and oxygen?

As shown in the following video, the central atom in Lewis Dot Structures is always the least electronegative atom of all the elements that make up the atom. 
https://www.khanacademy.org/science/chemistry/chemical-bonds/copy-of-dot-structures/v/drawing-dot-structures

This way, you would expect chlorine to be the central atom. However, it is shown that oxygen is the central atom.

The ambiguity exists for molecules like $\ce{OCl_2}$ as well. What's the issue? Is this not a very consistent rule of thumb?

Comment: isn't Chlorine the most electronegative?

Comment: That's fluorine.

Comment: No in your question you said that the central atom is the least electronegative, but then you state that chlorine should be the central atom. Is that a typo? Because the least electronegative in hypochlorous acid would be, between oxygen and chlorine, oxygen.

Comment: Isn't oxygen more electronegative than chlorine?

Comment: Yes you are correct, sorry I just checked. I guess it kind of depends on the moles in play. For OCl2, there's one oxygen atom and two chlorine, so it would seem like oxygen would be in the center with 2 chlorines branching out. Even if you tried to put chlorine in the center for OCl2 while drawing a dot structure, it would inevitably come out to a structure similar to H2O.

Comment: The rules for drawing dot structures leave a lot to be desired, that's the main issue. For example, most organic compounds are outright impossible to draw using only a formula and the rules. You couldn't draw OCl2 in any other way, and that goes for most other violations of the dot structure rules. Molecular orbital theory gives more accurate results. That said, other than "you *couldn't* follow the rules", I don't have a proper answer to this. I'm not so sure there is one.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of several questions: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/25128/what-is-the-lewis-structure-for-hclo?rq=1 , http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/13615/determining-central-atom-in-ncl3/13617#13617 , http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/16624/which-atom-goes-in-the-middle-of-a-lewis-dot-structure?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

The video is wrong if it says "the central atom ... is always the least electronegative atom".

There are chlorine oxides with Cl central such as perchlorate, chlorate and $\ce{ClO2}$, even though $\ce{Cl2O}$ has O central.

There are $\ce{SeCSe}$, $\ce{CAt4}$, $\ce{NI3}$ and $\ce{Li6C}$ each with the more electronegative element central.

Comment: How would you answer the question then? Is there always some level of doubt one would have when coming up with Lewis structures when just given the constituent atoms?

Comment: @Arjun I would have to say there is always some doubt.  For example HNCO, HOCN, and HCNO all exist, although HNCO is most stable.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isocyanic_acid  Additional guidelines beyond "the more electronegative element central" would be "H" is almost always on the outside, usually no lone pairs on "C", almost never more than one lone pair on nitrogen, no more than two lone pairs on "O" in a neutral molecule.